# Major NSTextView Rotation Problems

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-animation, nsview, nstextview

Bear with me on this one, as it's been frustrating me for a few days. This seems like it should be really simple, but for some reason I keep running into a series of frustrating problems. I've done more work on iOS in the past, and never had these kinds of problems that I'm having on OS X. I'm wondering if I'm not understanding something fundamental about the view architecture in AppKit. In particular, I am not very familar with the interaction between layer-backed views and plain views as I have not needed to animate anything on OS X before (and because iOS makes all views layer-backed by default).

Anyway, I'm having some major problems with trying to rotate an NSTextView object by 45 degrees. The text is for some labels that get placed in a larger custom NSView subclass, but most of that seems irrelevant to this specific problem. I'll go through what I've tried and the problems I had. The position of the labels is basically static, so I don't care about whether or not they are animatable or not. The labels need to be created and placed programmatically, not from IB, as their size and position is dependent on dynamically generated data. If it matters, the NSTextViews are using attributed strings.

1) I first did this the way that seemed most straightforward to me, which was simply to set frames for the NSTextView labels, added them as subviews to the graph object, and then called `[labelTextView setFrameRotation:45]` on them. This worked perfectly on Mountain Lion, but when I tested it on Lion the label height that gets drawn on screen gets increased mysteriously (even though when I log the frame afterwards it is unchanged). That isn't acceptable because I need it to draw a background color for the label so that it looks readable when overlaid onto the graph. So on Lion there is a bug or something in setFrameRotation as applied to NSTextView (or so it would seem). Does anyone know what is going on with that? It's very annoying that it works correctly on 10.8 but not on 10.7. SetFrameCenterRotation has the same problem. Making the view layer-backed, or not, seems to make no difference.

2) I next tried to do this using CATransform3DMakeRotation, after making the parent view and the NSTextView layer-backed. I used the line `labelTextView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI_4, 0, 0, 1.0);`, but the text view doesn't rotate when I do this. As a test, I tried the same thing using a plain NSView with a colored background, and it does rotate correctly. Does anyone know possible reasons why this wouldn't work with an NSTextView?

3) I tried enclosing the NSTextView in a NSView container and then calling setFrameRotation on that. This does rotate it correctly, but somehow triggers an infinite recursion in Core Animation that quickly consumes gigabytes of RAM unless I kill the process! Again, any ideas about what's going on there?!?

4) I tried all of this using Autolayout to position the labels AND positioning them manually by setting their frames. No differences in results either way.

5) I could do this using completely custom drawing, but that would be a LOT of work in this particular case. I'd rather not do that just to support 10.7. I also could try NSTextField to see if it suffers from the same thing in part 1), but that would be annoying because I want some of the features of NSTextView (this isn't just a single line blob of text).

What am I doing wrong here? I never imagined something this simple being this difficult to get working correctly on 10.7 + 10.8.

UPDATE:
I tried substituting NSTextField for NSTextView and the problem in 3) goes away (the paragraph styling isn't exactly how I want it yet, but I can possibly fix that). Any ideas on why NSTextView has such problems with being rotated where NSTextField apparently doesn't? That seems insane to me. I'll try NSTextField without the container next to see if it also suffers from the drawing glitch on Lion.

UPDATE 2:
I tried just using an NSTextField instead of an NSTextView and rotating it, and that also worked completely fine on both Lion and Mountain Lion. The visual glitch where the size of the text view changes after rotation also disappears. So I guess the answer is that NSTextView is just totally incapable of having its frame rotated without triggering multiple bugs (especially on older versions of OS X). If that's the case, and NSTextView isn't intended to be used that way, Apple's docs should probably say so. Can anyone confirm that that is the case?

Comment: I can only guess here but the fact that an NSTextView is a composition of a scroll view and some content view might play a role here.

Comment: Well, I wasn't using IB to create the NSTextView. You can create one without embedding it in an NSScrollView if you do it programmatically, which is what I was doing (because it's just supposed to be embedded in a larger view that is itself added to the content view of an NSScrollView). I guess it's possible that NSTextView makes some sort of assumption that it will always be embedded in its own scroll view (since Apple seems to make it inconvenient not to do that). In my case, I was only using NSTextView because it is more flexible for formatting multiline text than NSTextField.